# huggingface_load_dataset() function quit() without finishing

Tags: dataset

I try to use datasets to get "wikipedia/20200501.en" with the code below.The progress bar shows that I just complete 11% of the total dataset, however the script quit without any output in standard outut. I checked the cached directory and find the arrow file is just not completed.

```
wiki = load_dataset("wikipedia", "20200501.en", split="train", download_config=download_conf)
```

[image]

I tried several times and got different ratio of completion but never succeed in completing the progress.Could any one help me?

> env:python version:3.7
> datasets version:1.1.2
> MacOS

Comment: The function is "load_dataset()" and this is from the module "datasets" https://github.com/huggingface/datasets

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by unstable network connection. It can be solved by downloading the URL with browser or "wget" function.